# In consumable InAppPurchase, delegate of cancel transaction not found in ios5.1 but found in ios 6.1

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

On confirm your In-App Purchase, I am cancelling the purchase. 
In iOS 6.1 after cancel, control transfered to `- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions` method.

In iOS 5.1, no any delegate method will get called. So I am not able to control app on cancelling TRANSACTION.

My code to buy product:

```
- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product
{
    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);

    SKPayment * payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}
```

Delegate Method:

```
#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionOBserver

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    NSLog(@"updated transactions");

    for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                NSLog(@"SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
}
```

Please let me know what is the issue.

Comment: i think SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed get called when user cancel in app purchase.

Answer (score 2):

```
I found the solution. It was working in both iOS in device. The Problem is of validate receipt. If you are testing inApp purchase using test user then you need to use sandbox verify receipt that is
 #define  TMS_SANDBOX_VERIFY_RECEIPT_URL @"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt". but when you are uploading app to the appstore then you need to change it to 
#define ITMS_PROD_VERIFY_RECEIPT_URL  @"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt". 

So when user download the app from the app store then for the valid receipt verification 'ITMS_PROD_VERIFY_RECEIPT_URL' is must. otherwise it will give failed receipt verification. 

So please use  #define ITMS_PROD_VERIFY_RECEIPT_URL  @"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt" when you are uploading app to the app store.
```